# Android dashed divider in ListView

Tags: android, listview, divider

I'd like to draw dashed dividers for the listview. But I failed. There are a few similar questions in StackOverflow, but none of them fixed my problem.

Here are the steps I create the dashed divider:

- Create a list_divider.html

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <item>
      <shape android:shape="line">
          <stroke
              android:color="#ff0000"
              android:dashWidth="10px"
              android:dashGap="10px" />
      </shape>
  </item> </layer-list>
  ```
- My layout contains the list view

  ```
  <ListView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
      android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
      android:dividerHeight="1px"/>
  ```

Then in the preview inside the UI editor, it's like it works:

[image]

- 3.But unfortunate it doesn't work in emulator:

[image]

Can anybody give me a hint? Thanks.

P.S.: The reason I'm using layer-list is that I may need to draw 2 lines in the future.

Comment: did you tried it on a device?

Answer (score 5):

Its documented here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29944

You have 2 options:

- turn off hardware acceleration: `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`
- or: `listView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` or xml `android:layerType="software"`

It gave me too a headache!

Answer (score 0):

Did you name the drawable realy `list_divider.html`? Rename it to `list_divider.xml`. I'm surprised that it works in the UI editor.

A second thing which might have an impact: for the sizing of the divider use `dp` instead of `px` as units. In Listview and in divider xml. You never know how much 10 pixel are.

Comment: Sorry, that's my typing mistake. It's a xml. And I've tried dp too. It also doesn't work.