# App lags with android:layerType="software"

Tags: android, listview, hardware-acceleration

I am making a really simple app (basically a listview with only a few images). It generally performs really well on my testing device (a Motorola Moto G with the stock android that comes with it).

However, I want my ListView to have dotted dividers. Therefore I made a list_divider.xml file defining the divider and set this to be the divider to be used in the ListView. I have tried that out on my Moto G, but it didn't display the line dotted.

So I've googled around and found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24224599/1564218) a solution to the problem. Disabling hw acceleration for the view solved the error and displayed the divider correctly.

However, now I have another problem: Since disabling hw acceleration the app began to lag when scrolling.

Is there a solution to having a dotted divider and not disabling hw acceleration or at least have the performance nearly as good as before disabling it?

Edit: Here is the adapter code I use:

```
public class AstronautArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Astronaut> {

    public static final String TAG = "AstronautArrayAdapter";

    public AstronautArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Astronaut> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.astronauts_list_row, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RowViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.astronauts_list_row, parent, false);

            holder = new RowViewHolder();
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfAustronaut);
            holder.daysInSpace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberOfDaysInSpace);
            holder.country = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countryImage);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleOfAstronaut);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RowViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Astronaut astronaut = getItem(position);

        holder.name.setText(astronaut.getName());
        holder.daysInSpace.setText(Integer.toString(astronaut.getDaysInSpace()));
        holder.country.setImageBitmap(astronaut.getCountryImage(getContext()));
        holder.title.setText(astronaut.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class RowViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView daysInSpace;
        ImageView country;
        TextView title;
    }

}
```

Edit 2: Here are the two layout files in question:

activity_main.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/astronautsList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:layerType="software" />
```

list_divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="@android:color/black"
        android:dashWidth="5px"
        android:dashGap="1px" />

    <size android:height="3dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: that line: `holder.country.setImageBitmap(astronaut.getCountryImage(getContext()));` make it look like you're possibly doing Bitmap decoding (or even downloading) on the UI thread. Are you??

Comment: No. At the start of the app I download everything I want and save it locally. (The app does lag at the start, but I know that this is because of the downloads and it is wanted).

Comment: "save it locally" that still means that during that line call the bitmaps are getting read from the disk (I/O operation) and the decoded (CPU intensive operation). I'll write my suggestion in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

possible answer for the lag you're seeing is:

add this line inside the `dependencies` section to your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
```

and replace this line

```
holder.country.setImageBitmap(astronaut.getCountryImage(getContext()));
```

with

```
Picasso.with(context).load(/* insert the URL here */).into(holder.country);
```

and remove the code that is downloading all the images and saving locally. Picasso automagically download/decode the bitmaps and manage disk and ram cache for you.

**ps.:**

if you're not using Gradle:

1. You should change to Android-Studio and use Gradle
2. forget what I said about adding the line to the gradle file and just download the jar file from their [website](http://square.github.io/picasso/), put into the `libs` folder and make sure to mess on the project settings to make sure that jar goes inside your APK (I honestly do not remember how those settings work because I abandoned Eclipse long time ago)

Comment: Re #2: put it in `libs` and ADT does it for you, luckily Google didn't abandon ADT that much

Answer (score 0):

As you did not mentioned it, have you implemented the ViewHolder pattern?

As the ListView recycles views it has to inflate a layout and insert any text and images in. You normally call findViewById in this section of code which is quite expensive. The ViewHolder pattern solves this and is easy to implement.

See here for a great tutorial by Google

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: Yes, I do use a ViewHolder and it still lags.

Comment: Make the inner class static

Comment: You don't need private but otherwise code looks good might need layout file to be sure.

Comment: I will add it, just a moment ;)

Comment: Ok after seeing the other comments go grab this library called Picasso, it is really simple and handles image loading really well http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: As I couldn't find anything on its website, do you think that also with hw acceleration off (because that is what I need when I want dotted lines) it performs well? Because with hw acceleration my app already performs well.

Comment: I think ita because you are decoding bitmaps from a file and it will be really great with HW acceleration but poor without it. Download the jar and put it in your libs folder and then use the example code in your adapter. Pass the url of the image rather than downloading them at the start as it has a great caching system in built.